# Javascript promises deep in the stack

Tags: javascript, promise

I decided to have a fallback call to the server when creating a model in case we can't find a value from the information available locally. I want to have it async if possible, does it mean I have to make everything in this chain of code consume and return promises?

I'm going to use pseudo code to illustrate this point initially, as the call stack can be a little long and so we don't include things that aren't central to this question. Let me know if you need more to go on though.

```
function router() {
    if (condition) {
        controller.renderDocument(options);
    }
}

controller.renderDocument(options) {
    documentCollection.findOrCreateDocumentHolder(options);
}

documentCollection.findOrCreateDocumentHolder(options) {
    var model = this.findOrCreateDocument(options);
}

documentCollection.otherFunction(options) {
    // just to illustrate that there's several entry points to this kind of functionality
    var model = this.findOrCreateDocument(options);
}

documentCollection.findOrCreateDocument(options) {
    if (!options.type)
        options.type = resolveType(options);
    // other things that use the found options.type
    return model;
}

resolveType(options) {
    var locallyResolved = resolveLocally(options);
    if (locallyResolved)
        return locallyResolved;
    // try the server as a fallback
    var serverResolved = resolveFromServer(options.id);
    return serverResolved;
}

resolveLocally(options) {
    return stuff;
}

resolveFromServer(id) {
    return ajaxRequestResult();
}
```

Obviously the actual code is a bit longer and actually does stuff.

It feels excessive to make all of this use chaining promises for the sake of 1 possible ajax request down the pipe, especially as this will be a rare occurrence. The other alternative is to just make a synchronous AJAX request.

Are my only options to make everything use promises and whens, or to make it a synchronous AJAX request? Is there a nicer alternative? I'm thinking of C#'s await keyword, but I'm sure other languages have similar functionality.

Comment: Quick comment, all the "functions" past `router` are not declared with the correct syntax. You should add `= function` between each function name and its respective arguments.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It's just pseudo code, to illustrate the point. I could use the actual code and obfiscate it and all the rest, but really that code is just there to show an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to have it async if possible, does it mean I have to make everything in this chain of code consume and return promises?

Yes. Something that is potentially asynchronous must always return a promise, and must always be consumed as if it was asynchronous (promises enforce this anyway).

> Is the only other alternative to just make a synchronous AJAX request?

Yes, and you really don't want that.

> Is there a nicer alternative? I'm thinking of C#'s await keyword, but I'm sure other languages have similar functionality.

In fact, [async-await is coming to ECMAScript](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait) as well. But it doesn't make anything synchronous, it rather is just syntactic sugar for promises-everywhere.

Comment: That's a shame, it makes resolving this problem in the time frame allotted infeasible. Purity is great, until you apply it to reality. The async-await stuff is good news! Sadly I have to support back down to IE 8, but will be great for node stuff at least. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Okay, "infeasible" is strong and possibly a little petulant. Just tough!

Answer (score 1):

Once you start with promises they do spread around, no way around it really since once you go async you must either wait (not feasible) or pass callbacks (which promises solve).

My approach is to embrace them, you'll be more often returning promises then immediate values, but you'll always take care of handling success/error and have a consistent way of dealing with data flow.

There are many more sources of asynchronicity than AJAX requests and I really can't think of a case where I would require a synchronous return value in Javascript.

Comment: You're right, and I think I agree, the problem is moving a large scale SPA in that direction for one small bit of async, I think you can see how that feels wasteful.

Comment: How do you solve other AJAX requests? Use async: false in AJAX requests? That is already deprecated today and sucks for users since it blocks execution.

Comment: I never said that, I just offered that as an alternative. So the conclusion is that there's no nice way to do this that doesn't involve changing a lot of code for a potentially minor thing.

Comment: My point was if you have a large scale SPA, you probably have more than one source of async data

Comment: We use backbone.js, so normally the callbacks are handled in event handler functions that are set up to respond to changes from the data that's sent back. Call it syntactic sugar if you like. No such luck here.